# How to manipulate only the central values of words in string (not first and last)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

Given a string of text with a random array of words, I am trying to isolate the first and last characters in any substring containing only numbers. I want the first number to remain itself, and for the substring of whatever length to finish with added " * ". I want to convert a substring like so: "12345" to "1bcde*".  Or "115" to "1ae*". Or "1" to "1*".

I have figured out how to accurately replace numbers with the letter that I want them to become by the code below, but i am not sure how to make the iteration stop if the number is at the beginning (skip the first number's conversion) or end of the word (add *).

If the string provided is "Hi how are you 2 what is 344" I'd like it to become "Hi how are you 2* what is is 3dd*"

```
digits='1234567890'
decade="abcdefhij"


for i in digits:
    if i in s:
        s=s.replace(i,decade[int(i)-1])
```

I do not know very advanced python yet. Keeping it simple would be great! Things such as loops, find, count, enumerate, if etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fucn(digits, decade):

    digits = list(digits) # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    decade = list(decade) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']

    if len(digits)!= 1:
        for index in range(1, len(digits)):
            digits[index] = decade[index]

    return ''.join(digits)+'*'
digits='1234567890'
decade="abcdefhij"

print(fucn('1', decade),'1',sep=', ')
print(fucn('1234', decade),'1234',sep=', ')
```

output

```
1*, 1
1bcd*, 1234
```

without using ''.join

```
def fucn(digits, decade):

    digits = list(digits) # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    decade = list(decade) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    res = digits[0]

    if len(digits)!= 1:
        for index in range(1, len(digits)):
            res += decade[index]

    return res+'*'

digits='1234567890'
decade="abcdefhijk"

print(fucn('1', decade),'1',sep=', ')
print(fucn('12345', decade),'12345',sep=', ')
```

output

```
1*, 1
1bcde*, 1234
```

Comment: that looks great! is there anyway to do it without using the join function though?